# Java Method Unbounded Type or Class Return

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, unbounded-wildcard

I was reading [this](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2010/10/25/using-builder-pattern-subclasses) article, , about subclassing a builder class. I understood the article but there was one small bit that bothered me. There was this method,

```
public static Builder<?> builder() {
        return new Builder2();
}
```

When I changed `Builder<?>` to `Builder`, a raw type, the compiler would not compile the code. The error was,

```
Rectangle.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println(Rectangle.builder().opacity(0.5).height(250);
```

What was the additional information passed to the compiler using the additional `<?>`? I suspected it was the compiler which could not figure the right instance during compilation. If I remove the comment markers in (A) the code compiled and ran fine. All the time it was referring to the Rectangle instance. So, my guess is it was the compiler which failed.

It would be great if someone can point me to an article that explains this or leads to find out more information to this. Thanks.

I have pasted the code here:

```
public class Shape {

  private final double opacity;

     public static class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> {
         private double opacity;

         public T opacity(double opacity) {
             this.opacity = opacity;
             return self();
         }

 /* Remove comment markers to make compilation works (A)
         public T height(double height) {
             System.out.println("height not set");
             return self();
         }
 */
         protected T self() {
             System.out.println("shape.self -> " + this);
             return (T) this;
         }

         public Shape build() {
             return new Shape(this);
         }
     }

     public static Builder<?> builder() {
         return new Builder();
     }

     protected Shape(Builder builder) {
         this.opacity = builder.opacity;
     }
 }

 public class Rectangle extends Shape {
     private final double height;

     public static class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> extends Shape.Builder<T> {
         private double height;

         public T height(double height) {
             System.out.println("height is set");
             this.height = height;
             return self();
         }

         public Rectangle build() {
             return new Rectangle(this);
         }
     }

     public static Builder<?> builder() {
         return new Builder();
     }

     protected Rectangle(Builder builder) {
         super(builder);
         this.height = builder.height;
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Rectangle r = Rectangle.builder().opacity(0.5).height(250).build();
     }
}
```

Comment: The cast `(T) this` is not type safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What was the additional information passed to the compiler using the
>   additional `<?>`?

The additional information by using a wildcard `<?>` was, that the returned `Rectangle.Builder<?>` is the super class of all possible *generic* `Rectangle.Builder<T>` classes (see [Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)). And since `Rectangle.Builder<T>` is guaranteed to have a type argument T, that is itself a subclass of `Rectangle.Builder`, **as long as its generic typing is not ignored**, `Rectangle.Builder<?>` is also guaranteed to be at least of type `Rectangle.Builder<? extends Rectangle.Builder<?>>`. If you completely ignore the generics by removing the wildcard, this information is lost and **the code will be compiled as ordinary pre-Java5.0 code** (where generics did not exist). This is necessary for backward compatibility.

To see the difference, consider a subclass of Rectangle.Builder that ignores the generic typing:

```
public static class BadBuilder extends Rectangle.Builder {
    private double height;

    public BadBuilder height(double height) {
        System.out.println("height is set");
        this.height = height;
        return (BadBuilder) self();
    }

    @Override
    public Shape.Builder opacity(double opacity) {
        return new Shape.Builder();
    }

    public Rectangle build() {
        return new Rectangle(this);
    }
}
```

Note, that this class overwrites `Shape.Builder#opacity` *without* returning a subclass of itself. The compiler will not generate errors for this class (but it may warn you, that the class ignores the generic typing). So without the generic information, it is *legal*, to return the type `Shape.Builder` from the opacity method. As soon as you add a type argument to BadBuilder, this code will no longer compile:

```
public static class BadBuilder extends Rectangle.Builder<BadBuilder> // -> compile time error
```

So the reason you get the compiler error `cannot find symbol` is, because the class `Shape.Builder` does not itself declare the method/symbol `T Shape.Builder#heigth()`, and the declared method `T Shape.Builder#opacity()` does only guarantee, that the returned Object is of type `Shape.Builder`, as declared in the type argument of `class Shape.Builder<T extends Shape.Builder<T>>`. Therefore calling the method chain `Rectangle.builder().opacity(0.5).height(250)` will only work, if `Rectangle.builder()` is actually guaranteed to return a Builder, that is typed with a subclass of Rectangle.Builder. And this guarantee can only be given, if the generic typing is not ignored (as seen in the BadBuilder example).

When you add the method `Shape.Builder#heigth`, by removing the comment in your code, this error obviously goes away, because then the `Shape.Builder` object returned by `Shape.Builder#opacity` will also have the corresponding method. You could also remove this error, by re-declaring `Shape.Builder#opacity` in Rectangle.Builder like so:

```
@Override
public T opacity(double opacity) {
    return super.opacity(opacity);
}
```

If you do this, then it is guaranteed, that the returned Object of `T Rectangle.Builder#opacity()` is of type  `Rectangle.Builder`, as declared in the type arguments to `class Rectangle.Builder<T extends Rectangle.Builder<T>> extends Shape.Builder<T>`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This difference is because when you use a raw type in a method, it turns generics for ALL the things you do with that type.

For example, suppose `Builder` had a method `foo()` that returns a `List<String>`. If you call `foo()` on an expression of type `Builder<?>`, it will be type `List<String>`. On the other hand, if call `foo()` on an expression of the raw type `Builder`, the type of that expression is `List`, not `List<String>`, *even though the type `List<String>` is not related to `T` at all*. It gets treated as if the method `foo()`'s return type was the erasure of what it actually is.

So in your case, suppose `Rectangle.builder()` returned type `Rectangle.Builder<?>`. For convenience let's give a name to this `?`, say `X`. So you have `Rectangle.Builder<X>` (which inherits from `Shape.Builder<X>`) and you call `opacity()` on it, which results in `X`. We know because `X` is the type parameter of `Rectangle.Builder`, `X` must be a subtype of `Rectangle.Builder<X>`. So we can call `height()` on it.

However, if `Rectangle.builder()` returned the raw type `Rectangle.Builder`, and you call `opacity()` on it, it turns off generics on the method `opacity()`, so it returns the erasure of its return type, which is `Shape.Builder`. And you cannot call `height()` on that.

Answer (score 0):

I am one who asks similar questions. Thanks to the answers by [Balder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525088/java-method-unbounded-type-or-class-return/22530952#22530952) and [newacct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525088/java-method-unbounded-type-or-class-return/22546386#22546386). I tried to summarize it in layman's word which I can memorize.

- Without `<?>`, Compiler only knows the returned type is `Rectangle.Builder` and `Rectangle.Builder` is a subclass of `Shape.Builder` without any other information. Since by definition `T Shape.Builder#Opacity()` in class `Shape.Builder<T extends Shape.Builder<T>`, the best knowledge for Compiler is that the returned `T` is a subclass of `Shape.Builder`, therefore, method `opacity()` returns a type of `Shape.Builder` and this type cannot access method `height()`.
- With `<?>`, Compiler knows

  1. the returned type is `Rectangle.Builder<Something>`;
  2. this Type *Something* by definition is a subclass of
     `Rectangle.Builder`, because `T extends Rectangle.Builder<T>`;
  3. the returned type is also a subclass of `Shape.Builder<Something>`,
     because in definition `Rectangle.Builder<T ...> extends
     Shape.Builder<T>`.

By *Point 3*, Compiler knows that `T Shape.Builder#opacity()` returns a `T` that is Type *Something*; By *Point 2*, Compiler knows that the Type *Something* is a subclass of `Rectangle.Builder`, so after calling method `opacity()`, the returned type can access `Rectangle.Builder` 's method `height()`.

I hope the compiler really thinks like above.